# ¿Qué servicio se usa en Syfmony 5 para devolver un 403 en un eventSubscriber

Tags: symfony, error-403

Tengo montando un eventSubscriber para que controle que solo los creadores de contenido puedan publicar su propio contenido.
El flujo va bien pero no se como generar el 403 para que lo detecte el sistema:

```
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FinishRequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use App\Repository\GroupRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;



class GroupEditSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, GroupRepository $groupRepository)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
        //$this->accessDeniedException = $accessDeniedException;
    }

    /**
     * $uri[0]  
     * $uri[1] group
     * $uri[2] $group_id
     * $uri[3] edit
     */
    public function onKernelFinishRequest(FinishRequestEvent $event)
    {
        $uri = explode('/',$event->getRequest()->getrequestUri());
        
        if($uri[1] == 'group' && $uri[3] == 'edit' && is_numeric($uri[2])) {

            // Si es usuario anónimo.  
            // TODO revisar porque seguridad no funciona en estas rutas
            if( $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser() === 'anon.')
            {
                throw new AccessDeniedException();
            }

            // Si es usuario autententica pero no es el autor
            $owner = $this->groupRepository->findOneById($uri[2])->getOwner();
            if($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()->getId() !== $owner->getId()) 
            {
                // devolvemos un 403
                throw new AccessDeniedException();
            }
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'kernel.finish_request' => 'onKernelFinishRequest',
        ];
    }
}
```

¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Gracias.

Comment: No estoy seguro de si es lo que quieres hacer, pero has probado de usar el security bundle? `composer require symfony/security-bundle` Con este paquete te gebera un fichero `security.yaml` donde le puedes definir permisos por usuarios y rutas en funcion de los `ROLES`https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-authenticating-your-users

Comment: Buenas, @PavloB., Si lo tengo, y el security-bundle no me deja indicar que solo los autores puedan crear sus propios contenidos.

Comment: Funciona con roles https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html

Comment: Si, pero no existe un rol para determinar que un autor pueda editar su propio contenido.